# How can I send the selected rows of a DataGridView to a Datatable, BUT ignoring the first column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hellou to everyone.

I would love the assistance from you guys.

My problem is like this:

I have this datagridview which I fill using datasource (a query to a db table). I only created manually one column which contain a checkbox. When the binding is complete I can click the checkboxes to select the row and I can select multiples rows this way.

I want to put the selected rows into a datatable (so I can read it and do some sql queries with the information on it) BUT when I read the selected rows to put them inside a datatable I need to skip the checkbox column (the first one).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add the check/selected column to the datatable/datasource.  After that you can easily query the DT and pull just the selected rows either via a DataView or linq

Comment: Hi Harry, please always include some code to make other members life easier and a more valuable question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for future reference, I'm gonna post here how I fixed it.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        if (dgvPedidos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvPedidos.Columns)
                dt.Columns.Add();
            int i = 0;
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvPedidos.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvPedidos.Rows[i].Cells["chkPedido"].Value) == true)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[i][1] = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][2] = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][3] = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][4] = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][5] = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][6] = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][7] = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][8] = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                    dt.Rows[i][9] = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```